# Filter required partition field n unnest array of date

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to interrogate my table partitioned by a required **transactionDate** field.

I want to filter my data only on multiple dates to avoid recovering a lot of data but I have this error : `Query error: Cannot query over table t without a filter over column(s) 'transactionDate' that can be used for partition elimination`

My code :

```
DECLARE dates ARRAY < DATE >;

SET
dates = (
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(DATE(transactionDate)))
    FROM
        t
    WHERE
        transactionDate >= "1900-01-01"
        AND analyticsUpdateDate BETWEEN "2022-05-01"
        AND "2022-05-10"
);

SELECT * FROM t WHERE transactionDate IN UNNEST(dates)
```

How can I manage this error while not querying the whole table?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `dates` is empty, `transactionDate IN UNNEST(dates)` condition will be `false` and your query will return an error:

> Cannot query over table 'testset.t' without a filter over column(s) 'transactionDate' that can be used for partition elimination

```sql
DECLARE dates ARRAY <DATE>;

-- Sample table
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testset;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE testset.t PARTITION BY (transactionDate) OPTIONS (require_partition_filter = true) AS
SELECT n, p AS transactionDate, p AS analyticsUpdateDate
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 9)) n WITH OFFSET 
 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-04-01', '2022-04-10')) p WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
;

-- Your Query will retrun an error because `dates` is empty.
SET dates = (
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT(DATE(transactionDate)))
    FROM
        testset.t
    WHERE
        transactionDate >= "1900-01-01"
        AND analyticsUpdateDate BETWEEN "2022-05-01"
        AND "2022-05-10"
);

SELECT * FROM testset.t WHERE transactionDate IN UNNEST(dates);
```

Simple workaround for this is to add `IS NOT NULL` condition on the partition column like below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM testset.t 
 WHERE transactionDate IS NOT NULL AND transactionDate IN UNNEST(dates);
```